# fmincon using SQP algorithm not running

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I need to run the optimization of a 2 variables function for which I provide the gradients. The code runs normally for the 'interior-point' algorithm but it stucks after the first interaction when I try the 'sqp' algorithm. The first algorithm gives me 5% of error from the values I expected, so I really need to check if SQP gives me better results.

```
deltaml=10^(-4);
deltaE=10^(-2);

Eo=[0;1];
Elb=[0;0];
Eub=[100;100000000000];

Alg='sqp'

f1=[subs(fdelta,ml,ml+deltaml);subs(fdelta,E,E+deltaE)];
f2=[subs(fdelta,ml,ml+deltaml/2);subs(fdelta,E,E+deltaE/2)];

gradobj = (4*f2-3*f-f1)./[deltaml;deltaE];

objfungrad = matlabFunction(fdelta,gradobj,'vars',{t},'outputs',{'f','gradf'});

opts_grad=optimset('Algorithm',Alg,'TolFun',1e-16,'TolX',1e-16,'Display','off','GradObj','on');

[xgrad fval] = fmincon(objfungrad,Eo,[],[],[],[],[Elb],[Eub],[],opts_grad);>
```

**The error when running sqp is:**

```
Error using deal (line 38)
The number of outputs should match the number of inputs.
Error in C:\Program
Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\symengine.p

Error in C:\Program
Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\optim\optim\private\evalObjAndConstr.p>evalObjAndConstr
(line 135)

Error in C:\Program
Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\optim\optim\sqpLineSearch.p>sqpLineSearch
(line 287)

Error in fmincon (line 910)
[X,FVAL,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,LAMBDA,GRAD,HESSIAN] =
sqpLineSearch(funfcn,X,full(A),full(B),full(Aeq),full(Beq), ...
Error in symb_optm_ml_E_mult (line 54)
[xgrad fval] =
fmincon(objfungrad,Eo,[],[],[],[],[Elb],[Eub],[],opts_grad);
```

Comment: Don't you need a constraint function for the SQP algorithm?

Comment: Is it indeed necessary a nonlinear constraint? I'm pretty sure I've seen sqp codes without it and the problem itself doesn't need it. 

How would be a constraint where any values inside the range of each variable is acceptable